# Can I tell which encryption protocol is used for a page request in PHP?

Tags: php, ssl, https

We've got a few users out there still using older browsers that connect to our site using TLS v1.0. We're planning on removing support for TLS v1.0 soon but would like not do this without warning. One idea we've had is to (for the next couple of months) show a message to anyone connecting to the site using TLS v1.0 notifying them to upgrade their browser.

Is there any way of finding out the encryption protocol used in a PHP page? I've had a look through the data we get in `$_SERVER` and can't see anything that looks like what I need.